# Javascript not showing DIV on Chrome, works on Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, spinner

I'm having a bit of trouble with this code:

The div **ajaxImage**, which contains a .gif spinner is supposed to show up when I make the call to this function and hide when the process is completed. The spinner shows and hides properly when I'm on Firefox but it won't work on Chrome. Any ideas why this could be happening? Thanks.

```
function searchSegments(){

    document.getElementById('ajaxImage').style.display='block';
    var lat = mainMarker.getPosition().lat();
    var lng = mainMarker.getPosition().lng();
    var url = 'index.php?option=com_socialgo';

    var ajax = new Request.JSON({
            url: url,
            method: 'get',
            async: false,
            data:{
                'lat': lat,
                'lng': lng,
                "format":"raw",
                "option":"com_socialgo",
                "task":"ajaxsegments.getSegmentsByEvent",
                "tmpl":"component"  
            },
            onComplete: function(jsonResponse){
                setMacroSegments(jsonResponse);
                document.getElementById('ajaxImage').style.display='none';                  
            }             
    }).send();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you try visibility=visible/hidden instead of display=block/none

Comment: I already tried that, didn't work :P (Still worked on Firefox tho)